# how can I update value to both values and keys to Python dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Supposing we have this dictionary:

```
thisdict =  {
"brand": ["Ford","Renault", "Nissan"],
"Ford": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}
```

When I change the "Ford" key value to "droF", I want it to be changed in brand list as well and vise versa like this:

```
thisdict =  {
"brand": ["droF","Renault", "Nissan"],
"droF": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}
```

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: The only way to "change" a key is to insert it under your new name and delete the old key and all its values (or create a new dict).  The only way to change an element of the value-list is to replace it. There is no link between the values that automagically does such things.

Comment: You'll get good answers showing how to do exactly what you asked, but, honestly, it sounds like you may need a better data structure. Python classes allow you to encapsulate data in such a way that you can pass references to the instances around and change their data in one place...but this may involve rethinking your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use a dict comprehension that modifies both the keys and the values:

```py
replacements = {
    "Ford": "droF"
}

def modify(x):
    # if it's in the dict, return the value in the dict
    # otherwise default to itself
    return replacements.get(x, x)

thisdict =  {
    "brand": ["Ford","Renault", "Nissan"],
    "Ford": ["red", "blue", "green"]
}

modified = {
    modify(k): [modify(x) for x in v] for k, v in thisdict.items()
}

print(modified)
# {'brand': ['droF', 'Renault', 'Nissan'], 'droF': ['red', 'blue', 'green']}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, strings are immutable, which means that "changing" one is actually a replacement. So the only way to do what you're asking for is to replace the key, and then go through all the values and replace them.

You might think, *"hey, why don't I just wrap the string around a mutable class?"*. The reason is that a key should be immutable. So your want and your data structure is conflicting.